# Why don't US citizens emigrate?

Tags: united-states, european-union, immigration

The situation for many US citizens is becoming worse with each and every year, due to healthcare costs, debt of any kind (education, healthcare, housing), shootings, racial tensions, retirement poverty, etc.

I often asked myself why, even though I travel and get to know a lot of people abroad in Europe, I have never met any people who were born in the USA but chose to live in another country - for example, in Western Europe. US citizens could easily live in almost every Western European country as English is understood and spoken there by a lot of people, not only in the UK but also in the Nordic and Central European countries. Are US citizens even aware that such a possibility exists, or are there legal measures in the US to make emigration unattractive?

Comment: Living expenses can be the main concern, as well as job availabilities.

Comment: @Gary2 London is not the UK. The prices linked in your Economics question are massively inflated by virtue of London being one of the biggest and most powerful cities in the world. I can personally assure you that the rest of the UK is nowhere near that expensive.

Comment: Closers: while every one of the US's prospective emigrants each have their own stories, circumstances, and opinions, the collective body of the USA's emigration related policies are an objective political constant for all of them.

Comment: Emigration has a cost, people emigrate if that cost is compensated by the living standard improvement. But the salary they are willing to accept should compete with: 1) For skilled workers with the salaries accepted by migrants from depressed areas of southern and eastern Europe whose relocation costs are lower, distance and bureaucracy matter. 2) For unskilled workers with the salaries accepted by migrants of the rest of the world especially Middle East. That said few US citizens actually migrated to Europe as skilled workers, but in small numbers.

Comment: I think the statements of the question contain too much misinformation, so voted to "leave closed".

Answer (score 6):

- US citizens may be able to *visit* many countries without visa, but they cannot *emigrate* quite as easily. Emigration is relatively easy for well-educated Americans with prospects for a good job, but those can live well in the US, too.
- To get a job other than a highly qualified, highly paid one, they will need the local language.
- The US is crabby about releasing citizens from their citizenship and obligation to [pay taxes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbesfinancecouncil/2021/07/20/unaware-you-have-to-file-us-taxes-as-an-american-living-abroad-heres-what-you-should-know/). So they could get to pay in both places.

Comment: The last point is an annoyance but it's actually uncommon to have to pay taxes if your income mostly come from a professional job (i.e. not top executive).

Comment: Re taxes, you can usually deduct the amount of foreign tax paid from your US taxes, which means you don't get taxed twice, just pay the higher amount.  Simplistically, if your Lower Slobbivian income tax was $1500, and your US tax was $2000, you'd only owe the IRS $500.  It's rather more complicated: if interested, start here: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-tax-credit

Answer (score 5):

The other possibility is that despite what you might see on RT, CGTN or even some Western media, the situation in the US ins't *that bad* relative to other countries...

Also, most countries don't accept most kind of migrants nowadays but are "choosy" to let in only the well-educated etc. And the well-educated don't fare poorly in the US last time I checked... In fact I haven't seen evidence that the "brain drain" *to* the US has been abated much. Just a data point, albeit from 10 years go, [about](https://journals.openedition.org/belgeo/7094) two-thirds of Europeans who got a PhD in the US stayed there thereafter. (The issue still seemed to come up in EU political bodies deliberations [in 2015](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document//E-8-2015-003247_EN.html). A bit more [in-depth analysis](https://www.bruegel.org/2015/09/eu-immigration-to-the-us-where-is-it-coming-from-and-is-brain-drain-real/) finds that the source countries were somewhat skewed towards Eastern Europe, but not as much as you might think: approx. 33% from East, 27% North, 27% West, and 13% from South Europe. So if a non-trivial number of well-educated Western and Northern European choose to emigrate to the US, maybe it's not that bad [for them] over there...)

Comment: A very important point -- live in the US **can** be very good, including healthcare, retirement, etc., for those with enough money. Students with a PhD are not average workers.

Comment: @o.m. most ironic thing is those with enough money seem to be the ones who want free healthcare, free education etc... Those with not much money seem to oppose free stuff.

Comment: Bottom line:  if you're skilled enough to be taken in, no-fuss, as an immigrant in Europe, remaining in the US is probably not the worst of choices.  Many European countries also don't have the most positive outlook, be it economically, public sentiment ("are we headed in the right direction?"), or racial tensions.  Or even covid handling.  Always seemed to me the US could easily throw out the bathwater while keeping the baby.  Easier than some European countries could become dynamic.  Of course, the last 5-6 years can make one wonder how "fixable" the US problems are, but that's another story

Comment: @Ray if the people who'd end up paying the most for free healthcare are the ones who want it, that debunks the usual "they just want free stuff" rhetoric.

Answer (score -3):

Your question is based on a LOT of mistaken assumptions, and I say that as someone who has lived and worked in Europe, and who has friends who've either  done so, or have immigrated to the US from Europe.

To address the points you specifically raise:

1. healthcare costs: First, this should be MEDICAL costs.  Health care should be seen as the avoidance of getting sick or injured, and is relatively cheap, mostly involving exercise & diet.  Medical costs are an issue only if you need them.  In Europe, you usually pay most of these costs through taxes; in the US, either through insurance or self pay.  Either way, you still pay.

It's worth noting the tax to GDP ratio here.  The US takes considerably less than any western European country except Ireland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tax_revenue_to_GDP_ratio  Without detailed studies of budgets, I can't say where the money goes.

2. debt of any kind (education, healthcare, housing): This is of course optional.  It's quite possible to live in the US without accruing significant debt.  You may hear a lot about student loan debt, for instance, but what you hear about are the minority of foolish people who take out lots of debt for expensive schools and/or lavish student lifestyles, while majoring in a subject with really poor employment prospects.  Housing debt?  Unlike many Europeans, most Americans can own their homes, rather than paying rent, and (if sensible) can greatly profit by doing so.
3. shootings, racial tensions: Really not an issue in most of the US, and likewise not unknown in parts of Europe.
4. retirement poverty: Again, this is largely a matter of choices made throughout one's lifetime, and likewise not unknown in Europe.

On the other hand, to an American, most of Europe seems over-crowded, over-regulated, and over-taxed.  For instance, when I worked in Switzerland, I was amazed to discover that EVERYONE (not just foreigners) had to have their address registered with a government bureaucracy, the "Controle des Habitants".

Then there's the matter of opportunity.  If you look at the Forbes list of the wealthiest Americans, you'll discover that more than 10% of them are immigrants: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jenniferwang/2016/10/04/more-than-10-percent-of-the-forbes-400-are-immigrants-14-of-whom-are-richer-than-trump/?sh=31d2ecd94235  Maybe it's my lack of Google-fu, but I can't find a single instance of an American who became wealthy after emigrating to Europe.

Comment: "had to have their address registered with a government bureaucracy". Well, in most of the US if don't have this, you can't vote and probably not drive either. So you can be/feel free as a prairie dog without the gov't knowing much about your whereabouts, but not enjoy much rights as citizen of a modern country in the absence of such a registration in the US...

Comment: Oh, it was me.  The first paragraph about health care is not very transparent, to say the least.  US GDP health expenditure is just light years above other Western nations so claiming what you spend 1 way is just what you what you pay in tax otherwise is [misrepresenting the data](https://www.statista.com/statistics/268826/health-expenditure-as-gdp-percentage-in-oecd-countries/).  Ditto claiming that shootings happen at the same scale elsewhere.  They don't.  The question is a push question, but this answer isn't really making the US case very well.  The US has good points, just not these.

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica: Please try to understand what I actually wrote, not what you THINK I wrote.  Did I say that shootings (or killings by other means) happened at the same scale?  No, I said they are not unknown.  Re medical costs, you're link is behind both a cookie wall and a pay wall, so I can't very well respond.  However, I'd suggest making sure that you're comparing apples to apples.  You might also reflect on the tax to GDP ratio in the link I've added.

Comment: It is because you have f*ly no way in the EU to get even your first 1M. But the population density of the EU is only about twice of the US, furthermore people tend to concentrate in big cities. How overcrowding feels, that is the pop density in the big cities. Google streetview does not show too much difference (well I was not ever in the USA).

Comment: @Gray Sheep: Well, that first million CAN be done (J.K. Rowling comes to mind), but it's a lot easier in the US.  WRT crowding, I agree that big cities are pretty much the same.  It's just that in the US, and particularly west of the Mississippi, it's a lot easier to get out of the cities and away from them.  Take for instance the Ridgeway Path in Britain, or the mountains along the Rhone in Switzerland: even though you're in pretty open country, you can still see the urbanized areas below you.

Comment: @Gray Sheep: Just as an aside, you could say that I have emigrated, in a sense.  I grew up in the Northeast, but have lived most of my adult life in the West.  So add that to the reasons Americans generally don't emigrate.  The US is large & diverse enough that if they're seeking more congenial conditions, they can often find them by moving somewhere else in the country.

Comment: @jamesqf Ok, but there is some social insurance here, too. For example, you can not be fired because the boss has a bad day. Or that everybody has healthcare (very little exceptions). I think these are highly dysfunctional things and do not compensate the braindamaged tax levels (like 27% VAT or 40% income tax), and I would like more an US-like low tax / free market direction. But that thing, that if you don't have insurance or a huge bank account, then you die, that is hilarious to me. A world can not work on this way, it is inthinkably cruel.

Comment: @jamesqf I think some special insurance should exist in the USA, with obligatory parttake of everybody inside the borders, and which allows at least lifesaving treatment.

Comment: @Gray Sheep: And you likewise can't be fired for not doing your job well?  As for the rest, well, the answer to your question seems to be that most Americans who are in a position to emigrate prefer not to.  Even those of us who live & work abroad generally only intend that to be temporary, while immigration rates of skilled people from Western Europe suggests that there are those who prefer the US, with all its faults.

Comment: @GraySheep That would be called a tax. idk how you can say you hate tax so much, and then say you want more tax.

Comment: @user253751 Right... but I think, you still very need it. People are idiot, they do not think, and if there is the problem (sudden sickness, accident), they have a problem. Another thing: people can get a healthcare even if it costs more than the money they will earn in his entire life. What is the rationale? 1: It shows that life has not a monetary value 2: imagine if you or your son would be diagnostized with it... But also the EU is always lesser careful. I have heard a horror story from a 34 year old alcohol addict, with a cirrhotic liver. In Netherland. There is euthanasia in Netherland.

Comment: @user253751 His health insurance denied to pay him a liver transplant. But it paid his euthanasia. As I heard it, I wanted to become an amish.

Comment: @GraySheep do you suppose there is an infinite supply of fresh livers? They go to the innocent people who had some unlucky liver disease, when possible, not to people who willingly destroyed their own livers. This is the same under any reasonable system.

Comment: @user253751 1) He was yet young 2) afaik the request was rejected. The problem was not the available livers, but that already the insurance rejected to pay it. (Anyways alcohol addicts run obviously in the last for available livers, that is okay.) 3) euthanasia counts there just as an ordinary healthcare................................. like as if I get some pills for headache....

Comment: @jamesqf That is country-dependent. Yes, in Germany, that is not a valid fire reason.  If companies really want, they can of course fire people (like saying that the position, in which he worked, has ceased to exist), but it all requires a lot of paperwork, and if the ex-employee sues the company, the likely outcome is a "severence pay" between 10k-100k EUR. Such thing like "at will employment" in the USA is unheard and impossible. But that is no good: 1) there is a huge mass of nothing-doers on all levels of the companies 2) it is f*g hard to find a job.

Comment: @jamesqf An [example](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/173977/32611) of the effect of this... I think, in the USA, these people had been long fired, but they had found a new job quickly, and they would now work on some more useful...

Comment: @Gray Sheep: The fundamental problem is that the demand for medical care will ALWAYS exceed the available supply.  Whether it's lack of (suitable) donor livers, the US insurance company not being willing to pay, the European NHS-equivalent not being willing to pay (or not having capacity, which amounts to the same thing), or just a lack of surgeons & support staff to do the operation, there's always a limit.  (Just as e.g. COVID vaccines are limited by how fast they can be manufactured.)

Comment: @Gray Sheep: At the same time, a great many people are unwilling to take the simple and usually cheap HEALTH care measures that will greatly reduce their future need for MEDICAL care.  If it's drinking to excess, as in your example, or as we see in the US currently, being unwilling to wear cheap face masks, or get a free COVID vaccination, why should the rest of us be expected to pay for problems they cause themselves?